# Autofocus input somehow catching a keypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm implementing a couple of shortcut keys for my MVC web app and I'm running into an issue. The app allows users to answer multiple choice or short answer questions, and I'd like to make multiple choice questions answerable by just pressing 1,2,3,4 etc. Here's what I have right now:

```
$(document).on("keypress", function (e) {
  self.someKeyPressed(e);
});

[...]

someKeyPressed: function(e) {

  // locate all the multiple choice buttons in this view
  var buttons = this.$el.find('button');

  if(_.contains(_.range(49,55), e.which) && buttons.length) {
    index = e.which - 49;
    var answer = $(buttons[index]).text();
    this.answerQuestion(answer);
  }

  e.stopPropagation();
},
```

This works fine, except for the case when a multiple-choice question is immediately followed up by a short answer question. In this case, the same `<div>` used to contain the  elements, is instead replaced with:

```
<input placeholder="answer goes here" autofocus="autofocus">
```

And here's where the problem is: whatever shortcut I used on my keyboard to answer the multiple choice question shows up in the  as if the user had typed it in, even though that view didn't exist at the time of the keypress. I tried to wire up an event on "input keypress" and that doesn't even go off in this situation. Interestingly enough, removing autofocus fixes the issue, but unfortunately I need it for for the user experience to be pleasant.

What's going on here? Is there anything I can do to prevent the keypress from making it into the input until I'm ready?

**Edit**: it looks like adding `e.preventDefault()` right after `e.stopPropagation()` did the trick. Without it, the shortcut number would be typed into the input as soon as the jquery event dispatcher logic completed, but no sooner.

Comment: You could check that the `e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 90` to ensure it's 0-9 or a-z?

Comment: What do you mean that "view didn't exist at the time of the keypress"? Is it just hidden in the DOM? Then you can remove `autofocus` attribute and set focus with javascript when the input appears.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like calling `e.preventDefault()` does the trick, even though I'd still love to find out one day why exactly this makes a difference.